# how to set repeat count for svg-animate tag?

Tags: html, css, xml, svg, figma

I generated an SVG animation in figma, and this is the code:
( is svg-animate deprecated? i didn't find any docs even on http://www.w3.org/2000/anim ... )

Anyways I want to set iteration count on this animation to infinite loop, acording to `repeatCount = ""` is the code for svg `<animate>` tag but doesn't work here.

```html
<html>

<head></head>

<body>
    <svg-animate trigger="on">
        <svg viewBox="0 0 1782 472" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
            xmlns:anim="http://www.w3.org/2000/anim" anim="" anim:transform-origin="50% 50%" anim:duration="0.5"
            anim:ease="power1.inOut">
            <g id="740e5bf3ebc45098be863f5fa8137535">
                <g id="f345f36d50dbb1b385b649460668dde9">
                    <line id="57362c07ad6cbc18f9412812a20a22a5" x1="6.5" y1="219.652" x2="6.5" y2="270.117"
                        stroke="#5ABCF3" stroke-width="13" anim="" anim:y="0|-150" anim:delay="0" anim:duration="6">
                    </line>
                    <line id="ad5693aa5655841f41fb18fe027e9154" x1="35.2988" y1="259.74" x2="35.2988" y2="274.583"
                        stroke="#5ABCF3" stroke-width="13" anim="" anim:y="0|-160" anim:delay="0" anim:duration="6">
                    </line>
                    <line id="bd425ec9600f3285a1697f00cca45cc2" x1="62.5488" y1="258.266" x2="62.5488" y2="290.919"
                        stroke="#5ABCF3" stroke-width="13" anim="" anim:y="0|-170" anim:delay="0" anim:duration="6">
                    </line>
                    <path id="5d58dc83bbfdb438555a1ff6dc964eb0" d="M96.2578 273.045V323.509" stroke="#5ABCF3"
                        stroke-width="13" anim="" anim:y="0|-180" anim:delay="0" anim:duration="6"></path>
                    <path id="441201ac9ebb6b37fde82b7766f68762" d="M123.475 305.76V322.086" stroke="#5ABCF3"
                        stroke-width="13" anim="" anim:y="0|-180" anim:delay="0" anim:duration="6"></path>
                    <path id="5514f8d6be7375e761745c2478cc40b6" d="M153.799 255.301V328.029" stroke="#5ABCF3"
                        stroke-width="13" anim="" anim:y="0|-170" anim:delay="0" anim:duration="6"></path>
                    <path id="bb6efab68636240c634eaf89101ca21e" d="M181.107 241.926V316.138" stroke="#5ABCF3"
                        stroke-width="13" anim="" anim:y="0|-160" anim:delay="0" anim:duration="6"></path>
                    <path id="f2869d85d5ea05493ee7a21308fd6405" d="M209.865 261.215V270.12" stroke="#5ABCF3"
                        stroke-width="13" anim="" anim:opacity="0|-1.5" anim:delay="0" anim:duration="6"></path>
                    <path id="41ce5cf1e2ecd7f503ee96ade7b92ad3" d="M237.172 219.652V271.601" stroke="#5ABCF3"
                        stroke-width="13" anim="" anim:y="0|-170" anim:delay="0" anim:duration="6"></path>
                    <path id="3b8e35c6494aad3543f829785927e4d1" d="M265.939 204.822V244.897" stroke="#5ABCF3"
                        stroke-width="13" anim="" anim:y="0|-182" anim:delay="0" anim:duration="6"></path>
                    <path id="aafa85475a39042bfcc37f8037fe8b18" d="M322.018 200.357V238.948" stroke="#5ABCF3"
                        stroke-width="13" anim="" anim:y="0|-170" anim:delay="0" anim:duration="6"></path>
                    <path id="592a7c82ba79d5a84bb6704c15627335" d="M293.018 188.357V226.948" stroke="#5ABCF3"
                        stroke-width="13" anim="" anim:y="0|-179" anim:delay="0" anim:duration="6"></path>
                    <path id="01cace70f73240968466ca14b799d527" d="M350.828 218.189V290.918" stroke="#5ABCF3"
                        stroke-width="13" anim="" anim:y="0|-150" anim:delay="0" anim:duration="6"></path>
                    <path id="b2ee49cee68de07c2e110bd47f06b98e" d="M379.623 284.986V295.376" stroke="#5ABCF3"
                        stroke-width="13" anim="" anim:y="0|-208" anim:delay="0" anim:duration="6"></path>
                    <path id="67bedc874195a06674545b91ac467e8c" d="M406.9 290.92V339.9" stroke="#5ABCF3"
                        stroke-width="13" anim="" anim:y="0|-190" anim:delay="0" anim:duration="6"></path>
                    <path id="a477ddccc7fbf113bb98cac7371ee947" d="M435.684 335.447V363.648" stroke="#5ABCF3"
                        stroke-width="13" anim="" anim:y="0|-217" anim:delay="0" anim:duration="6"></path>
                    <path id="c22518b42775fa796041c71a3b216505" d="M466.004 325.049V388.871" stroke="#5ABCF3"
                        stroke-width="13" anim="" anim:y="0|-250" anim:delay="0" anim:duration="6"></path>
                    <path id="8c2e42827f8a4704a6f074982a98fdc1" d="M494.803 379.967V408.167" stroke="#5ABCF3"
                        stroke-width="13" anim="" anim:y="0|-261" anim:delay="0" anim:duration="6"></path>
                    <path id="62b0e008499736ca8701d2c34880be79" d="M523.557 390.354V440.818" stroke="#5ABCF3"
                        stroke-width="13" anim="" anim:y="0|-240" anim:delay="0" anim:duration="6"></path>
                    <path id="20c1c33968bffbe2a7f1ff8b0d1ef8b8" d="M552.35 428.934V440.808" stroke="#5ABCF3"
                        stroke-width="13" anim="" anim:y="0|-286" anim:delay="0" anim:duration="6"></path>
                    <path id="a011a20425a7160e1c10715813c609a4" d="M582.66 431.926V472" stroke="#5ABCF3"
                        stroke-width="13" anim="" anim:y="0|-291" anim:delay="0" anim:duration="6"></path>
                    <path id="4792bf4907868b8b40a7e007ed0fa604" d="M611.449 423.01V449.726" stroke="#5ABCF3"
                        stroke-width="13" anim="" anim:y="0|-291" anim:delay="0" anim:duration="6"></path>
                    <path id="ce5d9b1813a03aa4e631b15cee5c869c" d="M640.268 418.557V427.462" stroke="#5ABCF3"
                        stroke-width="13" anim="" anim:y="0|-300" anim:delay="0" anim:duration="6"></path>
                    <path id="38711501bb512591f8efc72826c70358" d="M669.062 369.588V420.052" stroke="#5ABCF3"
                        stroke-width="13" anim="" anim:y="0|-270" anim:delay="0" anim:duration="6"></path>
                    <path id="39676141a6c2917d4eb13d8817630973" d="M699.352 369.588V394.82" stroke="#5ABCF3"
                        stroke-width="13" anim="" anim:y="0|-270" anim:delay="0" anim:duration="6"></path>
                    <path id="cde6593bdc2545d0abfbf9fb51690275" d="M728.174 328.025V394.816" stroke="#5ABCF3"
                        stroke-width="13" anim="" anim:y="0|-260" anim:delay="0" anim:duration="6"></path>
                    <path id="a31c75bd80dc52a37fc450312dd0e437" d="M756.947 316.15V344.351" stroke="#5ABCF3"
                        stroke-width="13" anim="" anim:y="0|-180" anim:delay="0" anim:duration="6"></path>
                    <path id="b419d1e635624bbb3546db2ccae9b3ee" d="M785.725 323.574V330.995" stroke="#5ABCF3"
                        stroke-width="13" anim="" anim:y="0|-160" anim:delay="0" anim:duration="6"></path>
                    <path id="eebf7f6cfc392e87298813d534344dbf" d="M816.062 323.574V351.775" stroke="#5ABCF3"
                        stroke-width="13" anim="" anim:y="0|-170" anim:delay="0" anim:duration="6"></path>
                    <path id="baf0ea60f447be51ed96959a26f0013f" d="M844.834 335.447V363.648" stroke="#5ABCF3"
                        stroke-width="13" anim="" anim:y="0|-160" anim:delay="0" anim:duration="6"></path>
                    <path id="b6eef8ec729b56fc24747e6a22db4a0b" d="M873.615 356.217V406.681" stroke="#5ABCF3"
                        stroke-width="13" anim="" anim:y="0|-150" anim:delay="0" anim:duration="6"></path>
                    <path id="d890cda12394eae2ff0cb736002c62d6" d="M902.432 325.049V376.997" stroke="#5ABCF3"
                        stroke-width="13" anim="" anim:y="0|-180" anim:delay="0" anim:duration="6"></path>
                    <path id="380f67ba2b30bd0f00c158fa4f7f7873" d="M931.219 280.506V347.297" stroke="#5ABCF3"
                        stroke-width="13" anim="" anim:y="0|-170" anim:delay="0" anim:duration="6"></path>
                    <path id="b4c9ea567b708431c2232e89decfff73" d="M961.531 267.176V295.376" stroke="#5ABCF3"
                        stroke-width="13" anim="" anim:y="0|-180" anim:delay="0" anim:duration="6"></path>
                    <path id="459ec89cef285066705cc2d849f11330" d="M990.322 262.721V304.28" stroke="#5ABCF3"
                        stroke-width="13" anim="" anim:y="0|-160" anim:delay="0" anim:duration="6"></path>
                    <path id="18560e6e3f89d111337a84f3453b6fcb" d="M1019.1 241.926V268.642" stroke="#5ABCF3"
                        stroke-width="13" anim="" anim:y="0|-180" anim:delay="0" anim:duration="6"></path>
                    <path id="afeb41d46ed47acddafbaf1d972e7f96" d="M1047.89 191.475V258.266" stroke="#5ABCF3"
                        stroke-width="13" anim="" anim:y="0|-160" anim:delay="0" anim:duration="6"></path>
                    <path id="db8692c21382398cc6c91f88f722faa2" d="M1076.69 191.475V224.128" stroke="#5ABCF3"
                        stroke-width="13" anim="" anim:y="0|-180" anim:delay="0" anim:duration="6"></path>
                    <path id="b11f92612177fcca4bff732c80c446d5" d="M1105.5 141.016V209.291" stroke="#5ABCF3"
                        stroke-width="13" anim="" anim:y="0|-160" anim:delay="0" anim:duration="6"></path>
                    <path id="46df037a8ba21aae19e4fcf4eb93d972" d="M1135.8 127.629V154.345" stroke="#5ABCF3"
                        stroke-width="13" anim="" anim:y="0|-170" anim:delay="0" anim:duration="6"></path>
                    <path id="e6fb325e432d365e15e18aa6de309d31" d="M1164.59 123.209V133.599" stroke="#5ABCF3"
                        stroke-width="13" anim="" anim:y="0|-180" anim:delay="0" anim:duration="6"></path>
                    <path id="2a9cc47fd35fa221f21d01c8e00d5f75" d="M1193.37 127.629V157.314" stroke="#5ABCF3"
                        stroke-width="13" anim="" anim:y="0|-180" anim:delay="0" anim:duration="6"></path>
                    <path id="e09f65800394c0f61aea7f4a19416bbc" d="M1252.46 100.914V129.115" stroke="#5ABCF3"
                        stroke-width="13" anim="" anim:y="0|-180" anim:delay="0" anim:duration="6"></path>
                    <path id="806aa0050a44fc6a30f5f8752e0fa98e" d="M1222.17 114.297V141.013" stroke="#5ABCF3"
                        stroke-width="13" anim="" anim:y="0|-160" anim:delay="0" anim:duration="6"></path>
                    <path id="0dfb5d3407510a53786d0f30962e870e" d="M1281.28 108.365V176.641" stroke="#5ABCF3"
                        stroke-width="13" anim="" anim:y="0|-170" anim:delay="0" anim:duration="6"></path>
                    <path id="546445c243a3f68a38810232e7377027" d="M1310.07 152.881V179.597" stroke="#5ABCF3"
                        stroke-width="13" anim="" anim:y="0|-160" anim:delay="0" anim:duration="6"></path>
                    <path id="a2e9c1d1704af9036f95309b8e39fabb" d="M1338.87 141.016V169.216" stroke="#5ABCF3"
                        stroke-width="13" anim="" anim:y="0|-160" anim:delay="0" anim:duration="6"></path>
                    <path id="1e5ddd9d8165f03071908236da353d11" d="M1369.16 154.35V181.066" stroke="#5ABCF3"
                        stroke-width="13" anim="" anim:y="0|-150" anim:delay="0" anim:duration="6"></path>
                    <path id="3345e181b6bba8f8f8387131c4ba3907" d="M1397.97 166.227V234.502" stroke="#5ABCF3"
                        stroke-width="13" anim="" anim:y="0|-170" anim:delay="0" anim:duration="6"></path>
                    <path id="a9ee34f20db73b2da8eaefed92b6ecc8" d="M1426.74 164.758V173.663" stroke="#5ABCF3"
                        stroke-width="13" anim="" anim:y="0|-180" anim:delay="0" anim:duration="6"></path>
                    <path id="63d8c1eebc32c93c540ad5a01a8fed6b" d="M1455.53 99.4551V167.73" stroke="#5ABCF3"
                        stroke-width="13" anim="" anim:y="0|-170" anim:delay="0" anim:duration="6"></path>
                    <path id="de079761e91207fbb7507cbf58cd429c" d="M1484.35 99.4551V114.298" stroke="#5ABCF3"
                        stroke-width="13" anim="" anim:y="0|-160" anim:delay="0" anim:duration="6"></path>
                    <path id="3a8db6d309ffb826f5190e57edd6f6bc" d="M1514.64 38.5898V108.349" stroke="#5ABCF3"
                        stroke-width="13" anim="" anim:y="0|-160" anim:delay="0" anim:duration="6"></path>
                    <path id="a31f85f9c268e19e57d32b1742f608d0" d="M1543.43 25.2188V53.4194" stroke="#5ABCF3"
                        stroke-width="13" anim="" anim:y="0|-160" anim:delay="0" anim:duration="6"></path>
                    <path id="a792e7c75d70714c7814c9950add7b7d" d="M1572.23 38.5898V105.381" stroke="#5ABCF3"
                        stroke-width="13" anim="" anim:y="0|-170" anim:delay="0" anim:duration="6"></path>
                    <path id="cd2aeb28c0527e1f36f2d662916136a5" d="M1601.03 96.4902V105.396" stroke="#5ABCF3"
                        stroke-width="13" anim="" anim:y="0|-190" anim:delay="0" anim:duration="6"></path>
                    <path id="908227f3acb53b23ff5f4ec9a045dd0e" d="M1629.81 74.2246V100.941" stroke="#5ABCF3"
                        stroke-width="13" anim="" anim:y="0|-200" anim:delay="0" anim:duration="6"></path>
                    <path id="79312c280ed7975fd17925d8593b30f7" d="M1660.13 19.3086V84.6154" stroke="#5ABCF3"
                        stroke-width="13" anim="" anim:y="0|-190" anim:delay="0" anim:duration="6"></path>
                    <path id="fe347b23b3a868667cc97f87384187ad" d="M1688.92 0V51.9486" stroke="#5ABCF3"
                        stroke-width="13" anim="" anim:y="0|-180" anim:delay="0" anim:duration="6"></path>
                    <path id="05ab82757a0be12b63055e52bffd1c3f" d="M1717.7 11.8828V38.5992" stroke="#5ABCF3"
                        stroke-width="13" anim="" anim:y="0|-170" anim:delay="0" anim:duration="6"></path>
                    <path id="44810fe51a39bc6de22f1b33ce9b2be0" d="M1746.5 34.1289V43.0344" stroke="#5ABCF3"
                        stroke-width="13" anim="" anim:y="0|-180" anim:delay="0" anim:duration="6"></path>
                    <path id="4cffb934b49c9d49507b669cfe87532a" d="M1775.3 37.0957V63.8121" stroke="#5ABCF3"
                        stroke-width="13" anim="" anim:y="0|-170" anim:delay="0" anim:duration="6"></path>
                </g>
            </g>
        </svg>
    </svg-animate>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@figmania/svg-animate/lib/index.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

how can i make this animation repeat and loop?

Comment: Read all the comments on the publishers page: https://www.figma.com/community/plugin/980366185319754464

Comment: The attribute is called `anim:repeat=""`. I didn't find the documentation (that is really bad), but from what I can see it can take a number. "indefinite" doesn't work like you would expect. And then you replace like `anim:y="0|-150"` with `anim:y="0|-150|0"`.

Comment: @Danny'365CSI'Engelman should do an example of a web component that can do this 

Comment: I have no clue what the ``http://www.w3.org/2000/anim`` NameSpace does. Most comments on ``<svg-animate>`` say it works in the Figma editor, but doesn't work in the browser.